# True / false evaluation doesn't work as expected in Scheme

Tags: string, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm trying to compare two booleans :

```
(if (equal? #f (string->number "123b"))
      "not a number"
      "indeed a number")
```

When I run this in the command line of **DrRacket** I get `"not a number"` , however , when I 
put that piece of code in my larger code , the function doesn't return that string (`"not a number"`) , here's the code :

```
(define (testing x y z)

    (define badInput "ERROR")  

    (if (equal? #f (string->number "123b"))
          "not a number"
          "indeed a number")  

    (display x))
```

And from command line : `(testing "123" 1 2)`
displays : `123`

Why ?

Furthermore , how can I return a value , whenever I choose ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (testing x)
  (if (equal? #f (string->number "123b"))
      (display "not a number")
      (display "indeed a number"))
  (display x))
```

You were discarding the result of the `if` expression. The condition was working fine, but nothing was done with the resulting string, it just went ignored. The whole procedure now is returning `#<void>`, because `display` is a side-effecting operation with no value of its own. Also, I removed the `badInput` variable and the `y` and `z` parameters because they were not being used at all.

To return a value from a procedure, simply put the expression with the value you want to return at the end of the procedure's body - this explains why your code wasn't working, only the *last* expression returns a value, although you can do side-effecting operations (for example, calling `display`) with any expression before and including the last one.

As a matter of fact, your code can be written in a more idiomatic by returning a value, noticing that the condition in the `if` now actually depends on the `x` parameter being passed:

```
(define (testing x)
  (if (not (string->number x))
      (string-append "not a number " x)
      (string-append "indeed a number " x)))

(displayln (testing "123"))
=> indeed a number 123

(displayln (testing "123b"))
=> not a number 123b
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding the last edit to your question, I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
(define (convert originalNumber s_oldBase s_newBase)
  (if (or (not (string->number originalNumber)) ; validate error conditions first
          (not (string->number s_oldBase))
          (not (string->number s_newBase)))
      "ERROR"     ; if one of the input values is wrong, return an error message
      (begin      ; else
        <body>))) ; put the rest of the procedure's body in here
```

Or this, if you prefer to use a `cond`:

```
(define (convert originalNumber s_oldBase s_newBase)
  (cond ((or (not (string->number originalNumber)) ; validate error conditions
             (not (string->number s_oldBase))
             (not (string->number s_newBase)))
         "ERROR")  ; if one of the input values is wrong, return an error message
        (else      ; else
         <body>))) ; put the rest of the procedure's body in here
```

Comment: @ron you should've posted the real problem form the beginning, the question was out of context. See my edit, that should do the trick - in essence, you have to restructure your code to return at the appropriate points

Comment: @ron tried _what_ exactly? this question is about how to implement the validation part at the beginning of the procedure, my solution will work. The rest of your code might have errors, but that's unrelated to the current question.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is even though your conditional is evaluting to false, your just discarding that result.

What you've typed is equivalent to:

```
(define (testing x y z)

    (define badInput "ERROR")  

    "not a number"

    (display x))
```

Where `"not a number"` is just discarded.

To return it, try something like

```
(define (testing x y z)

    (define badInput "ERROR")  
    (cond

        ((equal? #f (string->number "123b"))
              "not a number")  

        (else (display x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of a function is the value of the last expression in its body. The last expression in your `testing` function's body is `(display x)`, so that's the value of your function. Since your `if` is not the last expression in the body and it does not have any side-effects, it basically does nothing.

If you move your `if` after the call to `display`, `testing` will display `x` and then return "not a number".

Comment: So how can I return the value (the string of the `if`) ?

Comment: @ron By moving it, so that it is the last expression in the body.

Comment: You could use a `cond` to get short circuiting

Comment: @ron No way around what exactly? What is it you're trying to achieve? Do you want the call to `display` to not execute (like if you did `return "Not a string"` before the call to `display` in an imperative language)? If so, just move it in the else-clause of the `if`.

Comment: @ron Just do `(if input-is-invalid bad-input body-of-the-function)`, i.e. move the function body in the else-clause of the `if`. There is no early return in Scheme. Btw: You could make your code a lot cleaner by using the variable list of your do loop instead of mutating your variables with `set!`.

Comment: @sepp2k: I did , but then I got this : ` expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
  arguments...:
   #<void>
   #<void>
   #<void>
   76`

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be an overkill here, but you can return values directly from anywhere by calling a continuation set up by `call/cc` (or `call-with-current-continuation`):

```
(define (primo args ...)
   (call/cc (lambda (k) (secundo k args ...))))

(define (secundo k args ... )
  ... do your stuff and whenever you feel like it,
  ... return a value by calling
  (k value)
  ....
  .... )
```